# Git change previous version to master

Tags: git, version-control

I have four times commit to my git. See log

```
f1f55a9     5 hours ago     user    UI improvement   master
17114a0     2013-04-16      user    enhancement
d72934e     2012-12-24      user    enhancement
bf81a9e     2012-11-27      user    origin
```

I would like to be `master` is the oldest one like this;

```
f1f55a9     5 hours ago     user    UI improvement
17114a0     2013-04-16      user    enhancement
d72934e     2012-12-24      user    enhancement
bf81a9e     2012-11-27      user    origin      master
```

Which command should I use to change master to the oldest one? I use git 1.8 on windows 7.This is my screenshot on GitStack.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reset your master branch to that oldest commit (and don't have any work in progress), you can do a:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard bf81a9e
```

But if you have to push that new `master`, you will have to force the push, which can be problematic for other users having already cloned the **[upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)** with a more different `master` history.

However, if this is purely local, you can reset `master` to any commit you want.

---

Note that what you see in the GitStack web interface is the upstream repo, not your local repo.
You can reset master locally, but you would still have to do a:

```
git push --force origin master
```

That would make the upstream repo reflects the new master, but with commit f1f55a9, 17114a0, and d72934e **no longer visible**: `master` would only reference one commit.

So make sure that won't disturb any other users before doing the `push --force`.

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye you "can't change" what? What is missing?

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye what command do you type to see the old result? `git log`?

Comment: I use GitStack for windows.It is Web UI

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye Before using the commands in this answer, be sure to checkout the `master` branch with `git checkout master`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice true, I have added that step in the answer.

Comment: @Vonc Can the others commit f1f55a9, 17114a0, and d72934e disappear? I need that versions and only change master.

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye sure: if you reset `master`, those commits are no longer accessible. If you still need them, create a branch first (`git branch tmp`), then reset master. Finally push both `master` (with `--force`) and `tmp`. Remmber: GitStack displays commits accessible by a branch. If you move that branch, commits no longer accessible by that branch disappear. They might still be visible from another branch, hence the '`tmp`' suggestion. Otherwise, they are left for a while in the reflog.